# CSV datetime format that will default to AM/PM in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Is there a text file (CSV) datetime format that Excel will present as MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss XM by default?  XM represents AM or PM.  A couple experiments like writing the text file with values like this:

```
10/25/2020 04:07:23 PM
```

still come up using 24-hour time (10/25/2020 16:07:23) when opened in Excel.

The background is that users are receiving a CSV that when they open it is opened in Excel.  They'd like to see AM/PM dates by default without needing to set the format in Excel.  Rewriting the code that generates the CSV to instead generate XML (XLSX) is not worth this presentation nuance.

Comment: Do they ever need to sort by date? If not, then maybe consider formatting that will force the column format as text (such as 10.25.2020 04:07:23 PM

Comment: Do you know what kind of type csv file did you use?

Comment: @Lee  I must confess I'm not sure what you're asking.  It is a text file with a header row and values separated by commas.

Comment: @JohnSpiegel,, as soon you/user received the CSV file ask to use DATA command then TEXT to COLUMN while this process it facilitates select Column and apply an appropriate data type,, for the Date column use the required DATE/TIME format,, which can be modified as many times after even finishing the Text to Column command!

Comment: @RajeshS Thank you, but that's outside of scope.  The issue is that inexperienced users want to see the dates show in the specific format at the moment they open the file.  So the requirement is to affect the formatting before Excel displays the data.  I expect it's not possible.

Comment: @JohnSpiegel then the only possibility left is implementation of VBA macro ,,, as WB Open event,, if u are interested please [edit] you post & add this to the post as well new TAG VBA!

Comment: @RajeshS  Thanks again.  It's an interesting idea but still has the same issue where it addresses the problem inside Excel instead of providing the value in the CSV in a fashion that Excel will default to presenting in the desired format.  At this point, prepending a tab character is working.

Answer (score 1):

So long as these values do not need to be treated as "real dates" when opened in Excel, you can use characters which will force Excel to treat the date strings as strings.

In your example, you could replace the `<space>` with `<NBSP>` (Character code 160)

Note that you may have to encode this as UTF-8 with a BOM in order that Excel interprets things properly.